# How to add <br>'s after three periods if the word before the space is longer than 3 characters

Tags: php

I am having the following example string:

```
$string = "Mr.Bean said: It must be great to know PHP. 
He added that IP 1.2.3.4 is the best IP address one could own. 
Mrs. Walter. Today is a wonderful day. Tomorrow, it will rain. 
This is really just some random text. Did you hear this singing bird? 
I visited Berlin yesterday. It was raining and Mr. Bean said hello. 
Mrs. Bean was also there. They have two kids.";
```

What I need is a way to add two br's (line break) each time when three dots were in the string while making sure it does not add the br's if the word before the dot is less than 4 characters so it does not split things like Mr. Mrs. Dr.

The result I am looking for based on the string above would be:

```
    Mr.Bean said: It must be great to know PHP. He added that IP 1.2.3.4 is the best IP address one could own. Mrs. Walter. 

    Today is a wonderful day. Tomorrow, it will rain. This is really just some random text. 

    Did you hear this singing bird? I visited Berlin yesterday. It was raining and Mr. Bean said hello. Mrs. Bean was also there. 

    They have two kids.
```

So what I am basically looking for is a function like:

```
$string = SplitString($string);
```

which would take care of the format that I am looking for.

UPDATE:

The posted solution works fine, except that domain names are split also.

Example string where it shows the issue:

```
    Bill Price reveals his new method for playing the diatonic harmonica, whereby anyone can convert their ordinary ten-hole diatonic harmonicas into lead instruments. “Coupling is a patented method; guaranteed to expand the harmonica's range and over-all capability.” The major key diatonic coupling formula for this method is disclosed at: http://example.com/. You’ll enjoy samples from Bill’s unique ten-song CD, “Taking the Lead”. This CD displays dynamic possibilities available when pairing/coupling two diatonic harmonicas together. The result is truly astonishing! The formula is free for visiting example.com. The CD is only $8, plus it can be used as a tutorial for learning the Coupling Method.
```

The snippet splits it like this:

```
    Bill Price reveals his new method for playing the diatonic harmonica, whereby anyone can convert their ordinary ten-hole diatonic harmonicas into lead instruments. “Coupling is a patented method; guaranteed to expand the harmonica's range and over-all capability.” The major key diatonic coupling formula for this method is disclosed at: http://example.

    com/. You’ll enjoy samples from Bill’s unique ten-song CD, “Taking the Lead”. This CD displays dynamic possibilities available when pairing/coupling two diatonic harmonicas together.

    The result is truly astonishing! The formula is free for visiting example.com. The CD is only $8, plus it can be used as a tutorial for learning the Coupling Method.
```

Besides that, it seems to work perfect! Maybe the trick is somehow to check if there is a space after the dot to prevent domains from being split?

Comment: If you use my version and want to try your space after the dot technique just change `explode(".", $string)` to `explode(". ", $string)` and `$pieces[$i] .= "."` to `$pieces[$i] .= ". "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = "Mr.Bean said: It must be great to know PHP. He added that IP 1.2.3.4 is the best IP address one could own. Mrs. Walter. Today is a wonderful day. Tomorrow, it will rain. This is really just some random text. Did you hear this singing bird? I visited Berlin yesterday. It was raining and Mr. Bean said hello. Mrs. Bean was also there. They have two kids.";
function splitString($str)
{
    //look for 2 full stops, then another full stop with at least 4 word characters in front of it
    preg_match_all('#(.+?\..+?\..+?\w{4,}\.)#',$str,$matches);
    return implode('<br><br>',array_map('trim',$matches[1]));
}
echo splitString($string);
```

Output:

```
Mr.Bean said: It must be great to know PHP. He added that IP 1.2.3.4 is the best IP address one could own. Mrs. Walter.

Today is a wonderful day. Tomorrow, it will rain. This is really just some random text.

Did you hear this singing bird? I visited Berlin yesterday. It was raining and Mr. Bean said hello.

Mrs. Bean was also there. They have two kids.
```

New version that makes sure there's no content immediately after the full stop:

```
$string = " Bill Price reveals his new method for playing the diatonic harmonica, whereby anyone can convert their ordinary ten-hole diatonic harmonicas into lead instruments. Coupling is a patented method; guaranteed to expand the harmonica's range and over-all capability. The major key diatonic coupling formula for this method is disclosed at: http://example.com/. You'll enjoy samples from Bill's unique ten-song CD, Taking the Lead. This CD displays dynamic possibilities available when pairing/coupling two diatonic harmonicas together. The result is truly astonishing! The formula is free for visiting example.com. The CD is only $8, plus it can be used as a tutorial for learning the Coupling Method.";
function splitString($str)
{
    preg_match_all('#(.+?\..+?\..+?\w{4,}\.($| ))#',$str,$matches);
    return implode('<br><br>',array_map('trim',$matches[1]));
}
echo splitString($string);
```

Output:

```
Bill Price reveals his new method for playing the diatonic harmonica, whereby anyone can convert their ordinary ten-hole diatonic harmonicas into lead instruments. Coupling is a patented method; guaranteed to expand the harmonica's range and over-all capability. The major key diatonic coupling formula for this method is disclosed at: http://example.com/. You'll enjoy samples from Bill's unique ten-song CD, Taking the Lead.

This CD displays dynamic possibilities available when pairing/coupling two diatonic harmonicas together. The result is truly astonishing! The formula is free for visiting example.com. The CD is only $8, plus it can be used as a tutorial for learning the Coupling Method.
```

Comment: after 3 full stops not 1 :D

Comment: it still doesnt match the OP's expected output.

Comment: Hi there, your snippet seems to work great. The only issue that I am still having is that it also splits domain names. Will update the original post as it's too long for here.

Comment: @milkshake I don't think the end of the expected output actually matches the requested changes. Marcus seems to be okay with how it's done it, but I am to be honest still not 100% sure how it's supposed to be working, but the expected output doesn't match the rule I've understood the question to be requiring

Comment: @MarcusWeller So it's not just character length before the full stop? It also needs to make sure that it's not part of a URI?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I simply want to prevent that for example names are split like Mrs. Bond and that domain names stay in tact and are not split. What I basically try to do is splitting a unformatted feed into readable sentences while making sure they stay in tact as good as possible. Sorry if the description is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @MarcusWeller I've updated the answer with a new version - let me know if that works how you expect

Comment: Seems to work fine except that it splits the text after two dots. For some reason it also seems to add some strange characters now and then as you can see here: http://i39.tinypic.com/10yi35l.png However, it's very close to what I am looking for. Could be that the strange chars that show up come from the feed though, so I will need to check that also. Again, sorry for such a messy description.

Comment: @MarcusWeller the strange characters will be an encoding mismatch

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want however the output is different than what you are expecting (Look ma, no regex):

```
function splitString($string) {
    $pieces = explode(".", $string); // Split string into array at each "."
    $count = count($pieces);
    $tally = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) { // Loop through each piece ignoring the last as it doesn't make sense to put a "<br />" after it.
       $piece = $pieces[$i];
       $words = explode(" ", $piece);
       if (strlen(trim($words[count($words)-1])) > 3) { // Check whether the last word in this piece is greater than 3 characters long
          $tally++;
          if ($tally % 3 == 0) { 
            $pieces[$i + 1] = '<br />' . ltrim($pieces[$i + 1]); // Prepend "<br />" to next piece and remove any preceding whitespace
          }
       }
       $pieces[$i] .= ".";
    }
    return implode($pieces); // Put pieces into a string
}
```

**Outputs**:

`Mr.Bean said: It must be great to know PHP.  He added that IP 1.2.3.4 is the best IP address one could own.  Mrs. Walter. Today is a wonderful day. Tomorrow, it will rain.  This is really just some random text.<br>Did you hear this singing bird?  I visited Berlin yesterday. It was raining and Mr. Bean said hello.  Mrs. Bean was also there.<br>They have two kids.`

It detects the following words as matching your criteria:

- Walter
- rain
- text
- yesterday
- hello
- there
- kids

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

$string =<<<`EOD`

Mr.Bean said: It must be great... to know PHP. He added that IP 1.2.3.4 is the best IP address one could own. Mrs. Walter. Today is a wonderful day. Tomorrow, it will rain. This is really just some random text. Did you hear this singing bird? I visited Berlin yesterday. ... It was raining and Mr. Bean said hello. Mrs. Bean was also there... They have two kids.
`EOD`;

echo str_replace("...", "
", $string);

If you want to know more:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

For best practice, try to use Heredoc syntax to declare the variable ($string):
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: This does not do what the author needs.